# Remove text between two certain characters (multiple occurrences)

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove the text inside the character "-" and string "\n"
(the characters as well)

For example, string = "hi.-hello\n good morning"
the result I want to get is string = "hi. good morning"

and for string = "hi.-hello\n good morning -axq\n"
the result I want to get is string = "hi. good morning axq"

I found these examples (as a reference on how to tweak the one I want)

```js
import re
str = "hi.)hello| good morning"
re.sub(r"(?<=\)).*?(?=\|)", "", str)
>>>'hi.)| good morning'
```

and also this one

```js
>>> import re 
>>> x = "This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]"
>>> re.sub("([\(\[]).*?([\)\]])", "\g<1>\g<2>", x)
'This is a sentence. () []'
```

and this one

```js
>>> import re 
>>> x = "This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]"
>>> re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", x)
'This is a sentence.  '
```

But I still can't get the syntax for my case. I want to learn the general syntax of this as well (i.e., customization).

Comment: Does `re.sub(r"-.*\n", "", string)` works for you?

Comment: You don't have to used regex. You can simply use ```replace``` to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works when you want to delete the text between one pair e.g. (-,\n). When the problem is to delete text between several different pairs then I have to look better into the function how it really works.

```
import re
str = "hi.-hello\n good morning and a good-long \n day"
re.sub(r"-.*\n", "", str)
>>> hi. good morning and a good day
```

Edit: I have found out the trick for several symbol pairs:

```
str = "hi.-hello\n good morning and a good-long \n day (delete this), bye"
strt  =re.sub(r"[\(\-].*?[\n\)]", "", str)
print(strt)
>>> hi. good morning and a good day , bye
```

For several pairs put all into the brackets `[<remove from>].*?[<remove to>]`. Then each symbol that you want to remove has the form `\<symbol to remove (start or end)>`. In this example `\-`, `\n` (or `\(\n)`).

Comment: yeah multiple occurrences. sorry for not making it clear at first